# How to create realistic animal hair and fur?

Tags: particles, hair

I am trying to make hair in blender for 15 days, but can't get a better result. i,m beginner not  more know about blender. I wanna to create every type of animal hair and fur.
[image: I wanna every part of hair look separately. Similar to that his mention in this image.]

[image: This is my result that is not according to my thought.]

[Here is my blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tp3IucPqety7VQJvmkjmx61jjGGUisrQ/view)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to work at least 3 things:

- The color of your hair, you can use an *Input > Hair Info (Intercept* output) as node in your material to create a gradient:

[image]

- Make the base of the hair thicker and the end thinner with the *Hair Shape* values:

[image]

- Give your hair system some *Children* > type > *Simple* and play with the *Clumping, Roughness* and *Kink* parameters to make the hair mor realistic:

[image]

Result (needs more work of course):

[image]